# Self-Signed Certificate working in OS X but not Windows

Tags: windows, https, google-chrome, self-signed-certificate

Im trying to create a self-signed certificate to use a HTTPS connection to access my internal site (jira.intranet.com). I have successfully followed this article https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74345/provide-subjectaltname-to-openssl-directly-on-command-line (3rd answer), to address Google Chrome complaining about no subjectAltName.

Here's the commands I have used.

```
openssl genrsa -out ca.key 2048
openssl req -new -x509 -days 3650 -key ca.key -subj "/C=UK/ST=State/L=Locality/O=Home/CN=Home Root CA" -out ca.crt
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout server.key -subj "/C=UK/ST=State/L=Locality/O=Home/CN=*.intranet.com" -out server.csr
openssl x509 -req -extfile <(printf "subjectAltName=DNS:jira.intranet.com,DNS:www.jira.intranet.com") -days 3650 -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt

openssl x509 -in server.crt -text -noout

Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            c6:0f:5d:0d:40:83:18:fb
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=UK, ST=State, L=Locality, O=Home, CN=Home Root CA
        Validity
            Not Before: Jul 27 22:14:13 2018 GMT
            Not After : Jul 24 22:14:13 2028 GMT
        Subject: C=UK, ST=State, L=Locality, O=Home, CN=*.intranet.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:f2:a4:2c:56:3e:81:56:fc:78:44:cc:f2:25:31:
                    b9:56:3d:41:fa:76:5d:b6:e0:f1:8d:3b:d9:ba:f4:
                    2e:0b:90:2b:9c:69:05:f8:68:4d:d4:b3:97:e4:4b:
                    c5:82:14:18:38:27:ad:fb:0c:e9:fe:cc:03:ed:49:
                    27:a0:f1:c7:00:a3:95:70:e9:9a:be:1e:55:3f:2c:
                    af:d8:e2:a8:1c:28:29:13:2f:b0:41:2c:66:b8:c8:
                    db:5b:c3:1e:51:bc:f7:53:59:4d:c9:14:42:7b:46:
                    08:d8:c1:78:5f:cc:92:3d:0c:4d:1e:bc:59:93:86:
                    0d:41:6f:2b:2e:00:57:ca:b0:a9:8f:ed:6b:f8:95:
                    d0:5b:f8:da:63:db:e9:05:24:2f:f7:e4:b2:b4:f7:
                    29:25:77:96:fe:56:18:ab:e9:72:68:b3:7e:eb:6d:
                    23:ad:63:5c:f5:77:65:42:e6:bf:9c:31:06:65:f0:
                    59:eb:03:70:c1:00:29:5e:90:9b:6a:c5:34:c6:a5:
                    bf:77:f9:a9:ae:c0:dc:68:41:45:4e:e1:d3:73:be:
                    bd:a1:02:ce:bb:2b:e5:55:19:1f:10:93:64:84:4f:
                    39:d0:86:d0:b4:cc:f4:66:2f:52:2f:44:9a:31:91:
                    05:69:b0:14:4f:e5:19:a1:c3:c5:3a:33:f1:5f:e5:
                    9a:87
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:jira.intranet.com, DNS:www.jira.intranet.com
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         20:d4:28:f2:aa:84:83:f2:f9:20:06:0b:1d:2d:cd:d6:ef:d6:
         9c:66:fa:55:af:f9:b0:c7:db:06:f7:ff:8d:b6:31:b5:35:03:
         36:59:93:59:f1:79:3a:f8:be:6a:6a:21:d1:9f:5c:a3:b4:95:
         34:02:22:e9:8b:ba:ac:7e:dd:68:73:17:d3:0d:c8:3f:c2:25:
         f9:d8:f0:70:7f:25:5f:cf:6b:84:fd:fe:8b:b0:77:44:4c:0c:
         cf:a4:83:35:75:df:3b:46:bd:c0:83:bf:9b:cc:39:fd:69:74:
         14:02:1b:c0:92:7f:c7:a0:fe:d2:48:03:04:f5:93:41:77:a2:
         e9:b5:fa:c4:f3:79:85:06:4b:55:71:31:29:b1:48:59:20:9e:
         1b:c6:08:e8:f0:12:8c:8c:f8:67:02:31:fc:31:5f:76:93:f0:
         0e:8f:d2:75:f6:77:42:60:8b:5a:c9:60:33:39:f7:01:0a:09:
         1a:ff:3b:94:33:4b:d1:9d:49:b2:63:7d:1d:d0:55:4c:db:8c:
         56:65:b5:7f:50:16:ee:ab:05:66:3b:75:7f:80:2c:94:00:1e:
         04:39:75:a7:81:89:6c:a0:37:ca:22:a3:7c:95:29:57:b2:b4:
         b4:a9:6c:ab:77:81:7d:c3:20:d5:57:43:73:29:b7:e1:ee:6c:
         a3:b0:5f:98
```

If I visit jira.intranet.com on OS X, view certificate, drag certificate to desktop, import to OS X KeyChain and change Trust Settings to 'Trust All' then I can visit the site and it is marked as secure, as per below screenshots.

[OS X Google Chrome Using Self-Signed Certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guulk.png)

If I now visit jira.intranet.com in google chrome but this time on windows, I am presented with the below screen, complaining of ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID.

[Windows Google Chrome first visit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FDha.png)

I expected this, as in OS X I expected I will need to add the certificate to be trusted on this device. However, I noticed it is reporting 'Windows does not have enough information to verify this certificate'. This I believe is my main issue, and I'm not sure how to address it.

I continued to add the same certificate I used in OS X KeyChain to Windows 'Trusted Root Certificate Authorities' with `certmgr.msc`.

[Adding Certificate to Trusted Root Certificate Authorities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYSW0.png)

This did not resolve my issue, screenshot below.

[Google Chrome / Windows not accepting certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tE57s.png)

So, I am unable to access my site on windows as 'Secure' when I can on OS X. I believe its something to do with the process I have used to create the certificate, but I am no expert in certificates and am unsure how to proceed.

Any help in this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, managed to get it working with below line to create the certificate.

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 3650 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout server.key -out server.crt -subj "/C=UK/ST=State/L=Locality/O=Home/OU=IT/CN=jira.intranet.com" -reqexts SAN -extensions SAN -config <(cat /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf <(printf "[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:jira.intranet.com,DNS:www.jira.intranet.com"))
```